# javac: not a directory: src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java

Tags: java

I am on chapter 3 of Headfirst Servlets and JSP.

This is my input to windows 7 command line:

> D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\beerV1>javac -classpath
>   C:\Tomcat\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;. -d
>   src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java

This is the error message:

```
javac: not a directory: src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I have `BeerSelect.java` in this directory: `D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\beerV1\src\com\example\web`

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying? That using an IDE would be easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified the directory of the `-d` flag. This flag is used to specify where the class file should be put. You probably want to change your command to something like this:

`D:\Workspaces\ServletsJSP\MyProjects\beerV1>javac -classpath C:\Tomcat\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;. -d bin src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java`

Assuming bin is where you want your class files.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I had not given the 'bin' directory.

Answer (score 7):

The `-d` flag is used to specify which directory to output to. You seem to have omitted it's argument, so it thinks you want to output into a directory called `src\com\example\web\BeerSelect.java`, which of course is not a directory.